# angular-google-maps ionic on iOS device

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

I try to add google maps to my Ionic app. Everything works great in the browser but not on the iOS device.

My problem is the search box. I can type in the place and I see the dropdown list. But when I select one of the list I have to press the "Done" button in the keyboard to update the input field.

I did not find any solution for this problem. And at the moment I'm not sure if I Ionic is the right tool for my app. Maybe this is too much for it.

Maybe someone here knows what I'm missing. This is the first time I use Ionic.

this is my code:

View

```
 <ion-view view-title="mapview">
   <ion-content class="has-header map-container" >
     <div class="angular-google-map-container" >
       <ui-gmap-google-map center="mapview.map.center" events="mapview.map.events" zoom="mapview.map.zoom" >
         <ui-gmap-search-box template="searchbox.tpl.html" events="mapview.map.events" ></ui-gmap-search-box>
       </ui-gmap-google-map>
     </div>
   </ion-content>
 </ion-view>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('XXXX')
  .config(function(uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
     uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
      'API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID': 'XXXX',
      'API_KEY_FOR_IOS': 'XXXX',
      v: '3.20',
      libraries: 'places'
     });
   })
  .directive('mapview', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'client/mapview/mapview.html',
      controllerAs: 'mapview',
      controller: function($scope, $reactive, $rootScope) {
        $reactive(this).attach($scope);
        this.map = {
          center: {
          latitude: 45,
          longitude: -73
         },
        zoom: 12,
        events: {
          places_changed: (searchBox) => {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            if (places) {
              this.map.center.latitude = places[0].geometry.location.lat();
              this.map.center.longitude = places[0].geometry.location.lng();
            }
          }
        }
      };
     }
    }
  })
  .run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put('searchbox.tpl.html', '<input id="pac-input" class="pac-controls" type="text" placeholder="Search" >');
  }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. You need to disable the data-tap, on the generated element. What that means is that you will need an additional directive, which looks something like the below:

```
.directive('disabletap', function($timeout) {
  return {
    link: function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container');
        // disable ionic data tab
        angular.element(container).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
        // leave input field if google-address-entry is selected
        angular.element(container).on("click", function(){
            document.getElementById('type-selector').blur();
        });

      },500);

    }
  };
});
```

Then finally remember to add the directive to the  element, and it should work.